# Appending only works for first li item

Tags: jquery

I have a menu like so:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown" id="123">
        <ul class="nav123">
            <li id="widget-products">
                <ul class="123">// this one is filled with content from the script below</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" id="1234">
        <ul class="nav1234">
            <li id="widget-products">
                <ul class="1234">// this one won't fill</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to fill both `<ul class="123">` and `<ul class="1234">` with content created from a json file when you hover over a `<li class "dropdown">`. 
For the first `<ul class="123">` the code works, but not for the second one. I think below script is probably messing up the class names or selects the wrong id since I use `closest()`. 
I tried everything for the whole day but can't figure this one out myself....

In short the script only works for the first ul. Does anybody can see what I'm missing?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', function (e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        var catId = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
        var catHref = $(this).closest('[id]').children('a').attr('href');
        menuWidget(catId, catHref);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    }
});
function menuWidget(catId, catHref) {
    var url = catHref + '/site.json';
    $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
        //building elements
        $('#widget-products ul.' + catId + '').html(productsHtml);
    });
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, use class name instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IDs must be unique**, use common class name as selector, Change your code as

```
<li class="widget-products">
```

*JavaScript*

```
$('.widget-products ul.'+catId).html(productsHtml);
```

Also you have additional quotes in `$('#widget-products ul.'+catId+'')`

Comment: off course missed that one completely... Thx for your time